# Complex Networks in Hive - Optimization Code

Tags: hadoop, optimization, hive, complex-networks

I have a problem with how to get my Hive code optimized.
I have a huge table as follows:

```
Customer_id     Product_id     Date     Value
     1               1         02/28    100.0 
     1               2         02/02    120.0 
     1               3         02/10    144.0 
     2               2         02/15    120.0 
     2               3         02/28    144.0 
    ...             ...         ...     ...
```

I want to create a complex network where I link the products through the buyers. The graph does not have to be directed and I have to count the number of links between them.
In the end I need this:

```
Product_x     Product_y     amount
    1             2           1
    1             3           1
    2             3           2
```

Can anyone help me with this?
I need an optimized way to do this. The join of the table with itself is not the solution. I really need an optimum way on this =/

```
CREATE TABLE X AS
SELECT 
     a.product_id as product_x,
     b.product_id as product_y,
     count(*) as amout
FROM table as a
JOIN table as b
ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id
WHERE a.product_id < b.product_id
GROUP BY product_x, product_y;
```

Comment: what is amount and how is it computed? can you also include your existing query?

Comment: Taking just the customer_id 1, he is linking product_id 1, 2 and 3.
The "amout" is the amount of times the product x has been bound to the product y. The existing query is just the join of the table with itself, using the teh customer_id as key, an group by using product_x and product_y.  (product_x < product_y)